# Is it possible to access the xmp metadata of a pdf using only the standard java library?

Tags: java, steganography

Is it possible to access the xmp metadata of a pdf using only the standard java library/api? Or do you absolutely have to have a third party library?

Comment: A .pdf is just a file. A file is just a sequence of bytes. The JDK provides capabilities to read a sequence of bytes. A third party library simplifies the interpretation of the bytes. But it is absolutely possible for one to use only the JDK to deal with .pdf files. I do not believe there are specific APIs in the JDK that deal with PDFs such as they have for .zip files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - the evidence:

> [PDFxStream](https://www.snowtide.com/) for Java is written in 100% pure Java, with no native components or dependencies. Its only requirement is a compliant Java 1.5 (or higher) JVM.

https://www.snowtide.com/help/3.2.0/accessing-pdf-document-metadata